# Is tabbing behavior affected when used inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently attempting to tab through some react components that I've (text inputs, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc) implemented (using material-ui). Something I've discovered is that tabbing through my components locally works as expected but as soon as I put it on the server, it skips through my checkboxes & radiobuttons (but tabbing to text inputs works fine).

The website that I'm displaying my react project on is built on backbone and I'm basically displaying an iframe with my react project inside that. Is it possible that this has some effect on a user's ability to tab through the components inside an iframe?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute, this might help you out.

Comment: @AdamH Thanks! I'll take a look with that :-)

Comment: Hope it helps. If it does you should post an answer to your question and mark it as the answer so others can find it in the future if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from above, I was able to figure out that when I render my react project inside the backbone project, some components such as my checkbox and radio buttons are wrapped inside a `<span>` tag and in order for it to be able to be tabbed I had to add the `tagIndex` attribute to it. Thanks everyone!