# Is it possible to add an attribute to a span tag that wraps my react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So in a previous post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52958203/is-tabbing-behavior-affected-when-used-inside-an-iframe?noredirect=1#comment92823847_52958203)) I mentioned that I have a problem with tabbing through my react elements. So I've discovered that the problem is that all my react components are wrapped in a `<span>` tag that makes some of my input fields (my checkboxes and radiobuttons) to be skipped when a user navigates with the tag button.

This is what it looks like inside the inspector

```
<span class="jss29 jss226 jss277 jss271 jss265 jss276" tabindex="0">
    <span class="jss231">
        <svg class="jss168" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
            <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path>
        </svg><input class="jss280" name="ChkBox" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value=""></span><span class="jss64">
    </span>
</span>
```

If I add the attribute `tabindex=0` to my root `<span>` tag, then I'm able to get the correct behavior that I want. However, I don't have any control over the root span tag because it is generated when my react component gets rendered

Is there a way I can add an attribute to the `<span>` tag that wraps my react component?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where does this class come from , is it from a CSS framework like react-material-ui? If yes, you can override it with a `className` prop

Comment: Hi @Dhiraj - Yes I'm using react-material-ui. I've tried `className={{tabIndex: 0}}` but it doesn't seem to show up inside the `span` tag

Comment: You usually add the class name which contains your CSS code , can you post your actual material UI code

Comment: @Dhiraj I'm trying to avoid adding it in CSS so what I did was I actually added it to the `inputProps` prop and what that did was it added the `tabIndex = 0` into the `input` attributes instead of inside the `<span>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `<Checkbox tabIndex="0" />`. See [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html). And if you want to add attribute to parent node you have to use something like;

```js
export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const node = this.myRef.current;
    node.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("tabindex", "0")
  }
  render() {
    return <Checkbox inputRef={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem is I don't have direct access to the span tag so I can't just insert the attribute `tabindex=0`

Comment: Is your span tag outside react app?

Comment: It's rendered by the `react-material-ui` css framework

Comment: Did you try using on the `react-material-ui` component itself?

Comment: Hey friend, I have edited the answer to suit your requirement. You usually put it on the component but if you want to put it on the parent, you may have to grab its reference and then set attribute. Hope that was useful.